# What are the parts used in the pololu QTRX - RC sensors

Tags: sensor, pololu

I am making a line tracking device project, the number one important part of the device is the IR sensor itself. Now part of the project parameters is that it must be a single board and be only using smd components.

With my previous i had a really good time and success using pololu's [QTR reflectance sensors](https://www.pololu.com/category/123/pololu-qtr-reflectance-sensors) and it already has a functional library that can be used in the arduino IDE (i went with SAMD21 uC). So as much as possible i would like to use this sensor and recreate it inn my board

The problem now is pololu does not say in its resource files what is the name of the sensors they using; so that i could search and buy them ( i would be needing 30 since i would be doing similar to the 31 high density ones.)

Thus the question:

Do you know what sensor is pololu using in their [QTR reflectance sensors](https://www.pololu.com/category/123/pololu-qtr-reflectance-sensors)

On a related note. As a backup plan i seriously plan on considering on de-soldering those sensors off the board if i could not get them. but there is still one problem. The pololu QTR has an ic that i could not find a datasheet off [This picture on the right](https://www.pololu.com/product/4301#lightbox-picture0J9199;main-pictures). What is this 622k IC and what does it do so i might be able to find an alternative, i have noticed that there is 1 of this IC for every 4 sensor.

Also the [QTR reflectance sensors](https://www.pololu.com/category/123/pololu-qtr-reflectance-sensors) comes in 3 versions, 2 of which are notable the QTR and the QTRX. Based on the description Both have the same type of sensors but the other one is "*lensed*". What do you think the purpose of each one? from reading the description alone i could only find that the current rating is the notable difference

Comment: no, just a personal project, and a self set parameters

Comment: i think that you may have forgotten to do basic research .... web search for `Pololu QTR reflectance sensor schematic` returns the schematics at the Pololu website

Comment: found a reference to Sharp GP2S60 sensor ... https://www.pololu.com/product/2456/resources

Comment: https://forum.pololu.com/t/qtr-8a-sensor/881

Comment: one entry at pololu forum says that they do not reveal their sensor part number, but give this link as being similar https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/optical-sensors-reflective-analog-output/546

Comment: @jsotola thank you for sharing, i can understand why pololu doesn't want to share the specific model of their sensors, the forum is old and im not sure if they are still using the same sensors for i have the new one. But the digikey link you gave have a very similar looking sensors

Comment: All that is missing though is what is that  622k IC chip what does it do. the library for might be relying on the function of this chip